# Why Scrollview is not working even after trying several times and using other methods(nested scrollview) also?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-constraintlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have tried various other methods such as using nested scrollview, removed bottom_of_bottom="parent" and other solutions that are provided here but none of them seem to have been worked, anyone knows how to tackle this one, please share your solution? Been 2 days stuck on this.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="700dp"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context="com.example.genmypassword.MainActivity">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_text_phone2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:hint="default: 1"
        android:maxLength="20"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.578"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/textView12"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.066" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E8FFEB3B"
        android:shadowColor="#FFEB3B"
        android:text="Number of passwords"
        android:textColor="#009688"
        android:textColorHighlight="#FFEB3B"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.058"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.552" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="325dp"
        android:text="front"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.242"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.485" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="325dp"
        android:text="in between"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.785"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.485" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="325dp"
        android:text="End"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.475"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.485" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="375dp"
        android:text="Tick for Yes"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.593"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.683" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:text="Tick for Yes"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.593"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.636" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
        android:text="Tick for Yes"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.593"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.46" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:text="Tick for Yes"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.593"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.419" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:background="#E8FFEB3B"
        android:shadowColor="#FFEB3B"
        android:text="Password length(Security)"
        android:textColor="#009688"
        android:textColorHighlight="#FFEB3B"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.061"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.119" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="#E8FFEB3B"
        android:text="alphanumeric"
        android:textColor="#009688"
        android:textColorHighlight="#FFEB3B"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.049"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.059" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="#E8FFEB3B"
        android:text="PIN(numeric)"
        android:textColor="#009688"
        android:textColorHighlight="#FFEB3B"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.048"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.07" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#E8FFFFFF"
        android:shadowColor="#FFEB3B"
        android:text="Must Contain(default Alphanumeric):"
        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
        android:textColorHighlight="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.061"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.127" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#E8FFFFFF"
        android:shadowColor="#FFEB3B"
        android:text="Upper Case"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHighlight="#009688"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.061"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.127" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="#E8FFFFFF"
        android:shadowColor="#FFEB3B"
        android:text="Lower Case"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHighlight="#009688"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.061"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.069" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="#E8FFFFFF"
        android:shadowColor="#FFEB3B"
        android:text="Passphrase"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHighlight="#009688"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.061"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.075" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#E8FFFFFF"
        android:shadowColor="#FFEB3B"
        android:text="Special Characters"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHighlight="#009688"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.061"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView7"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.26" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="#E8FFFFFF"
        android:shadowColor="#FFEB3B"
        android:text="Numbers"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHighlight="#009688"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.061"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.129" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="530dp"
        android:background="#8BC34A"
        android:text="GENERATE AND COPY"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.49"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.905" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="#8BC34A"
        android:onClick="save"
        android:text="GENERATE COPY SAVE"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.49"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/button" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:text="Tick for Yes"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.595"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.22" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
        android:text="Tick for Yes"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.595"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.174" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your text (Optional)"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.947"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/checkBox4" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_text_phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:hint="Enter the size (default: 8)"
        android:maxLength="10"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.722"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:background="#E8FFFFFF"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:shadowColor="#FFEB3B"
        android:text="see your            password(s) here"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHighlight="#009688"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.061"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView9" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewlast"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.37"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="330dp"
        android:text="Position:"
        android:textColor="#4E0F00"
        android:textColorHighlight="#FFEB3B"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.061"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/checkBox11"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.55" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:text="load"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.061"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.973" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[unable to scroll down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nGjf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use Nested Scroll view like the

```
     <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

     <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="16dp"
          android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          >

       // Your code here 


 </LinearLayout>

 </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not fixed the height of ScrollView try to set its height as match_parent instead of 700dp-

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
```

Comment: no, the checkboxes, edittexts, textviews will overlap then

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems  .

1) you need to change your scroll view from `android:layout_height="700dp"` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`.

2) you need to change your ConstraintLayout from `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Hope this will solve your problem .